# Ubuntu not booting UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I have windows 10 installed and I have just installed Ubuntu. When installing I chose the "install alongside Windows boot manager" option and everything seems to install fine. No errors. But there is never any way to choose to boot Ubuntu. What should I do? I have the PC in UEFI mode.

It says this:

```
Boot mode: UEFI
Boot priority order:
    Usb hdd
    Windows boot manager
    Hdd0
    Usb fdd
    Hdd1 samsung... The ssd
    Atapi: cdrom 
    Network boot ipv4
    Usb cdrom
    Network boot ipv6
```

Comment: Is ubuntu and win 10 in the same mode (legacy / UEFI)

Answer (score 1):

I keep saying this all of the time.  Ubuntu has a usability bug in its install program. It needs instructions on how to make uefi boot.  Go to Bios setup and you need to load the trusted uefi file.  The way I did it on my acer was to go to the security tab.  Then you set a password.  BE VERY CAREFUL and MINDFUL.. peck it with one finger twice to be sure.
If you mess this up, your laptop is nearly bricked, but someone can help you fix it with an external floppy disk.. yes floppy.. know anyone?

Once you set the password, some options will become available.  Try to I turned off tcp (not sure if that matters).  I also reset all certificates.  and then I added trusted boot file.  Try doing only last one I mentioned and see if that works by itself.

So when you add the trusted file (it will find the location for you..) add all the files you can.. and then set your password back to "BLANK".  That means **type nothing**.. no characters..Just hit the enter key twice..do it now before you forget your password.

Now you can go to boot order.  You will see something like yes0.  Or something new probably at the bottom.. Put that up top and boot away!

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok..  Did it.. you owe me votes..you and the person who asked for help.  Have a nice day.. and also complain to ubuntu.

Comment: Its nice to see an answer improved yo you got my vote on it because now the questioner may have a clue where to go about. :) Thank you.

Comment: Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

At start up access the BIOs setting menu by pressing F12 (may change to F2, F9 or maybe holding down de ESC key, deppends on your computer) and go to Boot option tab, you should see something about Boot order and a list of all installed OS, select Ubuntu and move it up and down using f5 and f6, move it to the top, save and exit. The next time you reboot you should see a purple window called Grub, here you will see all the OS options you have. 
Good luck!

Comment: There is no option. The only option is the windows boot manager.

Comment: You dont have an Ubuntu option on your BIOs menu? thats odd... could you post a picture of your available options?