# Grub not loading - Dualboot Ubuntu 16.04 Windows 10 at Acer Aspire E 15

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, acer

after searching for days for a solution on how to get my Dualboot System to start I am placing this question.
I have Windows 10 installed on my Acer Laptop an want to install Ubuntu 16.06 beside it. I have one hard drive where I made two partitions for the linux installation (swap an home). The partitions are visible when looking for example with the "compmgmt.msc" at windows. But Grub is not loading - it goes straight to windows. 
I tried to follow the instructions on the wiki https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EFI_Problembehebung/. The output of the nvram is listed below. The chapter about how to fix the "acer problems" is even more confusing. When I go to bios to add the ubuntu uefi files as trusted i get an entry for: hdd0 -> efi -> ubuntu. But the last step to add the "shimx64.efi" is not visible (there is no entry).
Below is the "efibootmgr -v" output for my installation. The problem is that even after installing Ubuntu without problems there is no entry listed in the NVRAM.
Can anyone help me? I think the installation was correct (the boatloader is placed at the "/sda" of the drive).
Thanks =)
Andre

```
> ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v BootCurrent: 0001 Timeout: 0
> seconds BootOrder: 0002,0001,2001,2002,2003 Boot0001* Linpus
> lite  HD(1,MBR,0x4294967223,0x800,0x1de1800)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
> Boot0002* Windows Boot
> Manager   HD(1,GPT,d30143e0-3bd2-4090-b0a7-697dc65108ba,0x800,0x2fd41)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
> Boot2001* EFI USB Device  RC Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM  RC Boot2003* EFI
> Network   RC ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dmidecode -t bios
> # dmidecode 3.0 Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs. SMBIOS 2.8 present. Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes BIOS Information  Vendor: Insyde
> Corp.     Version: V1.08  Release Date: 11/06/2015    Address: 0xE0000
>   Runtime Size: 128 kB    ROM Size: 4608 kB   Characteristics:        PCI is
> supported         BIOS is upgradeable         BIOS shadowing is allowed       Boot
> from CD is supported      Selectable boot is supported        EDD is supported
>       Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
>       Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
>       5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
>       5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
>       3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
>       3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)       CGA/mono video services are
> supported (int 10h)       ACPI is supported       USB legacy is supported
>       BIOS boot specification is supported        Targeted content distribution
> is supported      UEFI is supported   BIOS Revision: 0.0  Firmware
> Revision: 2.30
```

Edit: I am sorry for the bad format of the question but I see no possibility to add breaks to make it more readable.

Comment: see if this helps [http://askubuntu.com/questions/785494/ubuntu-not-booting-uefi](http://askubuntu.com/questions/785494/ubuntu-not-booting-uefi)

Comment: hey, thanks for the fast answer. That is what the link above (https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/EFI_Problembehebung/) is telling you to do if you are using an acer laptop. Like I wrote: I am looking for the ubuntu efi file to make it trusted. But even there is a entry called "ubuntu" there are no efi files inside.

Comment: EDIT: what is really confusing is: after you wrote the link i tried handling the problem again. And suddenly there were four efi entries inside "ubuntu". I made the one called "shimx64.efi" trusted and suddenly a grub menu started. But it was an old gnu grub version (which was on this laptop by manufactor because it came withoud OS). I can't load ubuntu with it.... and it should be gone because when installing windows 10 I formated this hard drive. More confusing: I went back to the ubuntu entry, trying to make the other efi files trusted.... they are gone again -.-^^

Comment: glad I could help.  "like" my comments and my answer to the link.  I see this problem all of the time.  That is why I posted with pictures.  Also place a usability bug on launchpad.net    The install screen needs a note to let people know to fix the BIOS.  More bug reports might make the next release.  It took me sooo long to figure this one out.